# Convert 6 digit color code to 3 digits

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

I want to convert given hex color to 3 digits if it's possible. For example:

```
#ffffff - #fff
#001122 - #012
#012345 - #012345
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

I found this regex in the google webs but I don't know how to use them :/

```
# shorten your CSS
sed -re 's/#(([0-9a-fA-F])\2)(([0-9a-fA-F])\4)(([0-9a-fA-F])\6)/#\2\4\6/'

# expand: the three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits
sed -re 's/#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])\b/#\1\1\2\2\3\3/'

# works in egrep too
grep -E '(([0-9a-fA-F])\2)(([0-9a-fA-F])\4)(([0-9a-fA-F])\6)'
```

Comment: Simply do concatenation, var color = '#001122'; output = `${color[1] + color[3] + color[5]}` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably a shorter and sweeter way, but you could perform simple char-comparisons between the characters of the hex-color and if necessary manually assemble the string, for example:

```
var hex = "#aabb00";
if ((hex.charAt(1) == hex.charAt(2))
  && (hex.charAt(3) == hex.charAt(4))
  && (hex.charAt(5) == hex.charAt(6))) {
    hex = "#" + hex.charAt(1) + hex.charAt(3) + hex.charAt(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be below code will help you:

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}

function rgbToShortHex(rgb){
    var hexR = Math.round(rgb.r / 17).toString(16);
    var hexG = Math.round(rgb.g / 17).toString(16);
    var hexB = Math.round(rgb.b / 17).toString(16);
    return "#"+hexR+""+hexG+""+hexB;
}

function getShortHexColorCode(code){
    var rgb = hexToRgb(code);
    return rgbToShortHex(rgb);
}
alert(getShortHexColorCode("#ffffff"));
```

Check fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/peu6bug1/1/)