# Making hex 3-digit converts it to 6-digits while using `rgb-hex` library as an input in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using [react-colorful](https://github.com/omgovich/react-colorful) & using it's `<HexColorInput />` component as:

```
<HexColorInput
    className="w-12 text-blue-gray-500"
    color={rgb2hex(selectedColor.rgba)}
    onChange={(hex: string) => {
        updateBackground({
            selectedColor: {
                ...selectedColor,
                rgba: hex2rgb(hex),
            },
        })
    }}
/>
```

The `color` prop acts similar to `value` prop on `input`. And `onChange` handler changes as you type in an input.

The problem right now is when I make the hex input to be 3-digits, it automatically converts it to 6-digits as I'm directly using `rgb2hex` function on the input.

How do I fix this?

Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-colorful-sketch-picker-ouz5t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to check if `hex.length` is equal to `4` & if it is, then I `return`:

```
<HexColorInput
  className="w-12 text-blue-gray-500"
  color={rgb2hex(selectedColor.rgba)}
  onChange={(hex: string) => {
    if (hex.length === 4) return
    updateBackground({
      selectedColor: {
        ...selectedColor,
        rgba: hex2rgb(hex),
      },
    })
  }}
/>
```

The source of `HexColorInput` specifically adds `#` to it so for any 3-digit hex, it makes it a 4-digit.

**Edit:**

The above answer doesn't return to previous value if I blur when `HexColorInput` contains 3 digit value like `#21b` so I cloned `HexColorInput` & removed a validation from it that also supported 3 digit hex.

My new `HexInput.tsx` looks like:

```
import React from 'react'

import { useEventCallback } from '../hooks'

const hex6 = /^#?[0-9A-F]{6}$/i
const validHex = (color: string): boolean => hex6.test(color)

// Escapes all non-hexadecimal characters including "#"
const escapeNonHex = (hex: string) => hex.replace(/([^0-9A-F]+)/gi, '').substr(0, 6)

type ComponentProps = {
    hex: string
    onChange: (newColor: string) => void
}

type InputProps = Omit<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'onChange' | 'value'>

export const HexInput = ({
    hex = '',
    onChange,
    onBlur,
    ...rest
}: Partial<InputProps & ComponentProps>) => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(() => escapeNonHex(hex))
    const onChangeCallback = useEventCallback<string>(onChange)
    const onBlurCallback = useEventCallback<React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>>(onBlur)

    // Trigger `onChange` handler only if the input value is a valid HEX-color
    const handleChange = React.useCallback(
        (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const inputValue = escapeNonHex(e.target.value)
            setValue(inputValue)
            if (validHex(inputValue)) onChangeCallback('#' + inputValue)
        },
        [onChangeCallback]
    )

    // Take the color from props if the last typed color (in local state) is not valid
    const handleBlur = React.useCallback(
        (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            if (!validHex(e.target.value)) setValue(escapeNonHex(hex))
            onBlurCallback(e)
        },
        [hex, onBlurCallback]
    )

    // Update the local state when `color` property value is changed
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setValue(escapeNonHex(hex))
    }, [hex])

    return (
        <input
            {...rest}
            value={value}
            spellCheck="false" // the element should not be checked for spelling errors
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
    )
}
```

Here's the complete example with a demo → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-colorful-sketch-picker-ouz5t?file=/src/HexRgbaBox/HexInput.tsx

Answer (score 0):

The common way to declare a hex color is using 6 digits. When using the 3 digits format, you are shortening the 6 digits format. This only works if the digits in the positions R (so 1,2), G (3,4) and B(5,6) are equals.

Eg: You can write `#00CCFF` in 3 digits format as `#0CF`, but you cannot do the same on `#425416`

Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32290952/7632511) can make my point more clear.

Comment: I know what the question is about, maybe you didn't understand the answer. As i said in the answer: the 6 digits is the standard. This should tell you that you can't avoid `rgb2hex` to do the conversion, because it is giving you a standard output. What you can do, is convert its output back to 3 digits. In the answer i told when you can and how to do so